# Delete just ASP files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a Windows Batch Script file that deletes *just* .asp files.

If I do:

```
del *.asp /s
```

This has the side-effect of deleting any files with the extension .aspx.  This is bad because I want to preserve files with the aspx extension.

Is there any solution to this problem that doesn't require installing a custom application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to do the trick on Vista:

```
for %i in (*.asp) do @if not %~xi==.aspx del %i
```

For more information

```
help for
```

There are all kinds of modifiers to variables:

> In addition, substitution of FOR
>   variable references has been enhanced.
>   You can now use the following optional
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
> %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
> %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
> %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
> %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
> %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
> %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
> %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
> %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
> %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
> %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                environment variable and expands %I to the
>                fully qualified name of the first one found.
>                If the environment variable name is not
>                defined or the file is not found by the
>                search, then this modifier expands to the
>                empty string
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that because del is a DOS-vintage command, it doesn't understand extensions longer than 3 characters.

There are several solutions I can see, only one of which you'll like and none of which fits your exact requirements:

- run manually and add the /p switch to prompt and skip aspx files
- install [powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx) (presuming you're on XP or newer), which should have a way to iterate over the files in a more fine-grained manner.  I'm not a powershell guru, but this may be the best choice because it's at least a Windows component instead of a custom application
- install GNU [findutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) and [coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) and delete the files the way you would on unix: "find directoryname -name '*.asp' | xargs rm".  Upside: it will work.  Downside: it is most definately custom
- write something in Perl or C or Java if you already have those installed on the box to do the same thing as you'd do in powershell

Comment: There is no `del.exe` (nor, as far as I can recall, has there ever been) it is build into `cmd.exe` (or `command.com`).

Comment: Fair enough; the point still stands.  Aside: try running del.exe - just make sure you're not in a directory that magically contains a file named ".exe".  Ouch.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell will do this. While `dir -r *.asp` will match `*.aspx`, you can easily refine the output:

```
dir . -r -inc *.asp
```

Using `-include` to match wildcards in PSH rather than `-filter` (normally faster) which matches with the Win32 API (with the same results as `cmd.exe`).

You presumably only want to delete files, so, for testing:

```
dir . -r -inc *.asp | ?{-not $_.PSIsContainer} | del -whatif
```

Use of `-whatif` to just list what would happen. Use `-confirm` to prompt to configurm the file deletes. For use in a scrip avoiding aliases, but listing what is done:

```
Get-ChildItem -path . -recurse -include *.asp | 
  Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer} |
  Remove-Item -Verbose
```